# Java array beginner confusion

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically I would like to store information about a train within arrays. I believe I would need to use a 2d array. I can't seem to get it working correctly. I want an array that will let me keep track of the number of empty and reserved seats on each car of a train. Is this going to work for me?

```
    int[][] seats = new int[4][10]; 
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row ++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
            car[row][col] = 0;
```

I want for this just to initialize all the seats to 0, signifying they are empty. I currently get an error message on the semi colon after int[4][10], it says "expected , {"

Comment: @nAvEeDkHaN he's getting a compile error not a runtime one

Comment: The `for` statements should be in a code block

Comment: you're missing the brackets

Comment: It's less about arrays and more about your code formatting. It says it's expected a {, add some {'s to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try and see if it helps. I think the IDE is looking for initialization syntax since that's what you are doing in the loops. I could be mistaken on exactly what's going on but the code will compile for you.

```
int[][] seats = new int[4][10];
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
            seats[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is valid, the only error is that `car` should be `seats`:

```
int[][] seats = new int[4][10]; 
for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
   for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
      seats[row][col] = 0;
```

Comment: Maybe your IDE is misleading you, try to restart it (clearing the project might also help)

Answer (score 2):

Well your first problem is that you have an array named "seats" but you are trying to initialize something called "car".  Nesting for loops like that without including the '{', '}' to delimit them is, at least, bad style, and maybe has the compiler confused?  The following works like a champ for me.

```
int[][] seats = new int[4][10];
for ( int rowIx = 0; rowIx < seats.length; rowIx++ ) {
    for ( int colIx = 0; colIx < seats[rowIx].length; colIx++ ) {
        seats[rowIx][colIx] = 0;
    }
}
```

...although it works equally well without the squigglies but I find that much harder to read.  I also think you should get in the habit of asking the array its length rather than assuming fixed size.  Thats what is going on in the seats.length and seats[rowIx].length calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use a basic class to store the information.

```
class TrainCar
{
     private int _emptySeats;
     private int _totalSeats;

     public TrainCar( int total )
     {
         _totalSeats = total;
         _emptySeats = total;
     }

     public bool fillSeats( int num )
     {
         _emptySeats -= num;
         if( _emptySeats < 0 )
         {
             _emptySeats += num;
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }

     public int getFilledSeats()
     {
         return _totalSeats - _emptySeats;
     }

     public int getEmptySeats()
     {
         return _emptySeats;
     }
}
```

And then just use an array (or `ArrayList`) of the TrainCar class

```
TrainCar[] cars = new TrainCar[ NUM_CARS ];
for( int i = 0; i < cars.length; ++i )
    cars[i] = new TrainCar( SEATS_PER_TRAINCAR );
```

Comment: I would do this, but this is for an Android app. I need the values to be passed and manipulated  between different activities. From what I have learned today, SharedPreferences is the way for me to do this, but only allows me to use primitive data types.

Answer (score 0):

In the fourth line, car needs to be replaced with seats.  It is also good form to keep track of loops with { }, even for single lines.

```
int[][] seats = new int[4][10]; 
for (int row = 0; row < 4; row ++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
    {
        seats[row][col] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax of the loop statement is not respected here : braces are needed !

[tutorial explaining the syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)